# List all NON-GENERATED sequences for a schema in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, sequences

In PostgreSQL there are 2 types of sequences:

- Sequences created by the user using CREATE SEQUENCE
- Sequences generated by the DB to back a column of type SERIAL

INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SEQUENCES returns both types of sequences.

What **SQL statement** can get a list of the **sequences created by the user** (WITHOUT the ones generated by the DB) for a specific schema?

P.S.: I'm using PostgreSQL 9

Answer (score 5):

For a generated sequence the "owning" column will be defined automatically so that *could* be a distinguishing factor.

But that can be done manually as well, so there is no way to tell the difference between:

```
create table foo (
   id_col serial not null
);
```

and

```
create table foo (
   id_col integer not null
);
create sequence foo_id_col_seq owned by foo.id_col;
```

But if that is OK for you, the following statement can get you that information:

```
SELECT s.relname as sequence_name,  
       t.relname as related_table, 
       a.attname as related_column,
       d.deptype
FROM pg_class s 
   JOIN pg_depend d ON d.objid = s.oid 
   LEFT JOIN pg_class t ON d.refobjid = t.oid 
   LEFT JOIN pg_attribute a ON (d.refobjid, d.refobjsubid) = (a.attrelid, a.attnum) 
WHERE s.relkind = 'S';
```

You'll get at least one row for each sequence by that query: the dependency on the schema it was created in.

For a sequence owned by a column you'll get another row with the table and column it belongs to.

Comment: pg_catalog.attr_def holds the original column definition. `\d` will only list the first foo with 'nextval' modifiers, the second one will have only 'not null'.

Answer (score 0):

The only difference *may (at the least)* be where it is defined. Entering `\d yourtable` will list serials in the modifiers column as nextval(...), but sequences defined afterward will not. `pg_catalog.attr_def` holds data to the actual strings that were used for definition.

I agree with horse that functionally there is no difference. Its akin to declaring something on one line or two but the same exact things happens. The *DB is generating all these sequences* and there is no *user sequences*. The only difference is in how they are declared and the only way this information is persisted is the actual strings that defined the column are held in the system catalogs.

From the system tables:

```
create view check_seq as
SELECT a.attname,
    relname,
    (
        SELECT substring(pg_catalog.pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid) for 128)
        FROM pg_catalog.pg_attrdef d
        WHERE d.adrelid = a.attrelid AND d.adnum = a.attnum AND a.atthasdef
    ) as "column def"

FROM pg_catalog.pg_attribute a
join pg_catalog.pg_class c on a.attrelid = c.oid
WHERE a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
and c.relname in ('foo')
ORDER BY a.attnum
;
```

Examples:

```
create table foo (
   id_col serial not null
);
select * from check_seq;

 attname | relname |             column def           
 ---------+---------+-------------------------------------
  id_col  | foo     | nextval('foo_id_col_seq'::regclass)


drop table foo;
create table foo (
   id_col integer not null
);
create sequence foo_id_col_seq owned by foo.id_col;
select * from check_seq;

 attname | relname | column def
 ---------+---------+------------
  id_col  | foo     |
```